# How to search and replace with enclosed characters a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, io

Given a textile how can I replace all the tokens that have `%` at the beginning for `[]`. For instance in the following text file:

```
Hi how are you? 
I %am %fine.
Thanks %and %you
```

How can I enclose all the characters with `%` with `[]`:

```
Hi how are you? 
I [am] [fine].
Thanks [and] [you]
```

I tried to first filter the tokens and then replace them but maybe there is a more pythonic way:

```
with open('../file') as f:
    s = str(f.readlines())
    a_list = re.sub(r'(?<=\W)[$]\S*', s.replace('.',''))
    a_list= set(a_list)
    print(list(a_list))
```

Comment: is each word that starts with a `%` followed by a space?

Comment: yes @MattR, any other pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\B%(\w+)', r'[\1]', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKRFfM/1)

**Details**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary, there must be start of string or a non-word char immediately to the left of the current location
- `%` - a `%` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`). Replace with `(\S+)` to match 1 or more non-whitespace chars if necessary, but note `\S` also matches punctuation.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/O7JsV4):

```
import re

s = "Hi how are you? \nI %am %fine.\nThanks %and %you"
result = re.sub(r"\B%(\w+)", r"[\1]", s)
print(result)
```

Comment: I also have this cases `%hi_there` I would like to convert them into `[hi_there]`, is this working for such cases?

Comment: @anon See my answer: *`(\w+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more word chars (letters, digits **or `_`**).* It will.